# How to return errors from Expresss object on a node listening http

Tags: node.js, express

newbie on node
I have an web form that calls a node http server running a java applet. This works fine. This works great and prints errors to the console.

I want the errors or "success" notice to be sent back to user after the applet has run.
This is running on a listening http server. I've tried many adaptations. Here is the code:

```
   var express = require('express');
   var app     = express();
   ...

app.get('/processfile', function(request, response) {
   java.classpath.push("../lib/commons-io-2.4.jar");
   ...
   try {
   var g2rdf = java.callStaticMethodSync("com.pck1.processfile.Runner",     
   "nodejs", request.query.user,  request.query.pass, request.query.file);
    } catch (ex) { 
    console.log(ex.cause.getMessageSync(); }

    <-- does response go here ? -->
    });


   <!-- do I add a callback to server? -->   
   var httpsServer = http.createServer(app);
   httpServer.listen(8080);
```

The app get invoked from a form with a jquery process form on the index.html page

```
   $.get('/processfile', { user : userName, pass : password, file : fileName, auth })
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you render a custom error view ?

Or return an HTTP error :

```
response.send(500, { error: "something is wrong" });
```

edit : More info about send() method at http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.send

Comment: newbie here. where does that go?

Comment: Replace your comment "<-- does response go here ? -->" by my code and try ;)